# Calling threading.get_ident() returns same ID between different threads

Tags: python-3.x, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading, multiprocessing-manager

While I was learning to use **SyncManager** sharing common object among multiple processes, I noticed a odd behavior of **Thread** working in the context of **SyncManager**.

To my understanding, **SyncManager** creates a server process, accepting connections from other processes then invoke the target method using a **Thread**. (https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/multiprocessing/managers.py#L184)

However, in my example code below, the thread id get by calling `threading.get_ident()` turns out the same value.

I added a **RLock** version of the called method, together with a non-locked version. From what I can see from timeline of the log, it's behaving as expected - different threads calling the `cube` method, but how comes the same thread id?

I understands that same thread id may occur in another thread after a last thread is terminated. But it doesn't explain the behavior without **RLock**.

```py
from multiprocessing import Process
from multiprocessing.managers import SyncManager
import time
import os
import logging
import threading
from threading import RLock


class MyManager(SyncManager):
    pass


class CommonObj:
    def __init__(self):
        self.logger = logging.getLogger(
            "COMMON-%d-%d" % (os.getpid(), threading.get_ident())
        )
        self.lock = RLock()

    def cube_lock(self, x):
        with self.lock:
            self.logger.info("lock acquired")
            time.sleep(3)
            result = x * x * x
        self.logger.info("lock released")
        return result

    def cube(self, x):
        self.logger.info("cube called")
        time.sleep(3)
        result = x * x * x
        self.logger.info("cube finish")
        return result


def worker(cube):
    logger = logging.getLogger("WORKER-%d" % os.getpid())
    logger.info("calling common_obj.cube")
    result = cube(2)
    logger.info("result is %d" % result)


def main():
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
    MyManager.register("CommonObj", CommonObj)
    processes = list()
    with MyManager() as manager:
        common_obj = manager.CommonObj()
        print("Calling cube without RLock:")
        for i in range(3):
            p = Process(target=worker, args=(common_obj.cube,))
            processes.append(p)
            p.start()

        for p in processes:
            p.join()
            print("joined %r" % p)

        print("\n\nCalling cube with RLock:")
        processes.clear()
        for i in range(3):
            p = Process(target=worker, args=(common_obj.cube_lock,))
            processes.append(p)
            p.start()

        for p in processes:
            p.join()
            print("joined %r" % p)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

```
Calling cube without RLock:
INFO:WORKER-1389:calling common_obj.cube
INFO:WORKER-1390:calling common_obj.cube
INFO:COMMON-1388-123145579134976:cube called
INFO:COMMON-1388-123145579134976:cube called
INFO:WORKER-1391:calling common_obj.cube
INFO:COMMON-1388-123145579134976:cube called
INFO:COMMON-1388-123145579134976:cube finish
INFO:COMMON-1388-123145579134976:cube finish
INFO:WORKER-1389:result is 8
INFO:COMMON-1388-123145579134976:cube finish
INFO:WORKER-1391:result is 8
INFO:WORKER-1390:result is 8
joined <Process(Process-2, stopped)>
joined <Process(Process-3, stopped)>
joined <Process(Process-4, stopped)>


Calling cube with RLock:
INFO:WORKER-1394:calling common_obj.cube
INFO:COMMON-1388-123145579134976:lock acquired
INFO:WORKER-1395:calling common_obj.cube
INFO:WORKER-1396:calling common_obj.cube
INFO:COMMON-1388-123145579134976:lock released
INFO:COMMON-1388-123145579134976:lock acquired
INFO:WORKER-1394:result is 8
joined <Process(Process-5, stopped)>
INFO:COMMON-1388-123145579134976:lock released
INFO:COMMON-1388-123145579134976:lock acquired
INFO:WORKER-1395:result is 8
joined <Process(Process-6, stopped)>
INFO:COMMON-1388-123145579134976:lock released
INFO:WORKER-1396:result is 8
joined <Process(Process-7, stopped)>
```

Answer (score 0):

Oops, declared the logger in `__init__`, I need some sleep.